# Count amount of non-continuous blocks in an image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, imagemagick

I'm running a project about online digital embroidery. For the part of cost calculation, I need to know how many non-continuous blocks in an image. As the image blow, there are 12 blocks in the image.

Origin image:

[image]

The result that I expect.

[image: Demo image]

Sorry, I can't provide any online coding example for this question. I totally have no idea how to implement this feature. No matter frontend or backend technology, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I would use something like `potrace` to convert the bitmap to a vector, and then count the number of closed strokes in the output (and maybe add 1 for the backrgound).

Comment: You can do that with -connected-components processing. See https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php. Post your input image without the red numbers.

Comment: @xenoid It's interesting. Could you provide any excutable example please?

Comment: @fmw42 I'm still trying hard to understand how connected-componets work.  would be appreciated if there are any other examples.

Comment: @fmw42 imagemagick convert 1.png -define connected-components:area-threshold=410 -connected-components 4 -auto-level 2.png. After the command, I got an output image. How do I get the amount for the blocks?

Comment: Add -define connected-components:verbose=true to your command before -connected-components 4

Comment: @fmw42 I just realized that you need my origin image, sorry about that, the image has added in my question.

Comment: @fmw42 I've also posted the result on https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=37636.

Comment: See my reply there.

Answer (score 1):

These problems are hard. Even humans will make errors.

Eg the example you provided has 13 blocks, not 12 as I see it. You missed the block between the legs just above 11.

If I am wrong I would argue  why is the black (12) of the cup counted it could also be the back of the cat (10).

### Flood fill.

A flood fill algorithm can solve the problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835810/3877726) has a simple flood fill algorithm written in JavaScript and using the Canvas 2D API. To use the image must not taint the canvas (same origin or appropriate CORS headers)

**Note** you will also need to have a fill threshold if the image is anti-aliased or was encoded as jpeg (or other lossy compression)

**Note** this will only work for images with a few flat colors. Images containing gradients, or shapes that are counted as one but have many colors (due to shadows, lighting, highlights, reflections, etc..) can not be counted using this method.

#### To count blocks

Rather than fill with a color, fill with alpha = 0 (Transparent).

Steps

```
Let block count represent number of blocks. Set to 0

Start at the top left most pixel.
Repeat following steps until you have reached bottom right most pixel

Start search
    If the pixel is not transparent 
        Apply the flood fill at that pixel
        Add 1 to block count
        Repeat from start search
    If the pixel is transparent
        move right one pixel, if past right edge move down one and start at left
        Repeat from start search
```

Once you have competed the steps you will have the number of separate items in the image.

The flood fill algorithm can also easily give you the area of a block, (count the number of pixels filled), give you the size (width, height) and location (top, left, right bottom) of each block.

The only problem will be image noise (due to anti aliasing and compression artifacts). This would give you many small disconnected blocks along color edges. Use the number of pixels in the fill to ignore fills with less than a 100 or so pixels. In the image you provided the smallest block is around 400 pixels in area.

Comment: Wow, really nice explaintion. Yeah, you're correct! it's 13 blocks, I missed one. Could you please write me an excuable example? I'm not very familiar with html5. I've built one which can load image as bitmap data from url https://jsfiddle.net/cqmn5rpa/1/. Could you help me for the part of block amount counting?

Comment: I have no idea how to do with html5.

Comment: @peggy This is done via JavaScript (client side) not HTML, or if server side you have many language choices depending on the server you are using. You will need to have some programming experience as there are no off the shelf solutions that I am aware of.Sorry but without that experience there is not much I can do to help.